# Rails cache :duration not expiring

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I have this in my HAML view:

```
- cache "home", :duration => 15.minutes do
...etc...
```

But after waiting 15 minutes, the page has not updated. It looks like the duration cache is not working... What can it be? Is there something else I need to do to use :duration on my cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use hash option below instead of `:duration`

```
:expires_in => 15.minutes
```